Trying to get Masonry-style image container using Tailwind and React
I'm trying to get accustomed to using CSS more and I'm making a mini-project right now.  The major issue I am having right now is that I am trying to fill a container with images in a masonry-style format that populates the container from left to right before going onto the next row, but I have not found the solution to this problem, despite following some other guides online.
export default function ImageContainer ({ showImages }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const apiKey = import.meta.env.VITE_CAT_API

    fetch(`https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=20&breed_ids=beng&api_key=${apiKey}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`Fetch rejected: ${response.status}`)
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(data => setData(data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='absolute top-0 grid grid-cols-4 gap-3 m-5'>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index} className={`${showImages ? `animate-slideIn` : null} opacity-0 my-3`} style={{ "--delay": index * 0.05 + "s" }}>
          <img src={item.url}></img>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )

The animate-slideIn translates the image and makes it appear in the container, with a time delay that increases as the index of the item increases.
I'm using grid, but there's a lot of negative space in between the images. I also tried using flex-columns but that populates the container from top-down until it fills that column.
I tried following the solution to calculate the appropriate CSS sizes using the guide in https://w3bits.com/css-grid-masonry/ but I'm not sure how to utilize the JS function in the JSX part of the code.
If anyone can offer some tips or point me in the direction of the answer, please let me know because I've been stuck on this for awhile. Thanks.
